# Convert text in different languages to date

Tags: python, date

I've got 3 variables which are dates, but they are string and are in different languages(polish, romananian and bulgarian).

For example:

```
18 grudnia 1969
18 decembrie 1969
18 декември 1969
```

I want convert them to date but I don't know if I must write some enum with months in different languages or python(3.2) offers some method which helps me with it (I can't find id).

Comment: Can you use a third-party project for internationalisation, such as Babel? Or are you forced to depend on the stdlib alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use Babel, then I may have a possible solution for you. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/988517). It uses your exact example.